# Chain animation with a text view

Tags: android

The normal position of the textview is at the middle,than it goes to the right side, then its coming from the left side to the right side and stops at the middle(the normal position). 
i tried to make an animationset of textview that will do a move from the middle(it normal position) to the right side of the screen and than come from the left side of the screen to the middle(normal position, like a chain move.

```
public void Slide2(View v)
{
    AnimationSet animation=new AnimationSet(true);
      animation.addAnimation(new TranslateAnimation(0,v.getWidth(),0,0));
      animation.addAnimation(new TranslateAnimation(Animation.slide_in_left));
      animation.setDuration(300);
      v.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Comment: why you dont use android:ellipsize="marquee" for text animation

Comment: i want to write it in java code